# Layout Drawer doesn't add new view in a new line

Tags: android

Hy!!

If i want to add a textview and a textedit, both are in the same line

I have a Linear Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:text="@+id/EditText01" 
        android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

What i have made wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `android:orientation="vertical"` to your LinearLayout. By default, it adds items horizontally.

EDIT: Also, your `android:text` attribute shouldn't contain an `@+id/`, it defines what is displayed in the TextView. Only your `android:id` attribute should have that.